# $v^{\top}Av$ bounded between the smallest and largest eigenvalue of $A$ if $A$ is symmetric and $v$ is a unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix of order $n$, and let $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ be the smallest and largest eigenvalue of $A$ respectively.

Prove that for any unit vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$, $$\lambda_{min}\le {}v^TAv{}\le\lambda_{max}$$

Not sure how to start. I am given a hint on $A$ having $n$ eigenvectors which form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $v = \sum_i a_i v_i$ where the $v_i$ are your orthonormal eigenvectors. Then you have

$$v^T A v = \left(\sum_i a_i v_i^T\right) A\left(\sum_i a_i v_i\right) = \left(\sum_i a_i v_i^T\right)\left(\sum_i a_i Av_i\right)$$

But then $Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$ so you have

$$v^T Av = \sum_i a_i^2 \lambda_i v_i^T v_i.$$

What do you know about the $v_i$? If $\lambda_i \ge \lambda_{\text{min}}$, what do you know about $a_i^2 \lambda_i$? I'll let you take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ be the eigenvectors of $A$, which by the hint, form an orthonormal basis. Then rewrite $v^\top A v$ using the decomposition $v = c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n$.

> $v^\top A v = v^\top (c_1 \lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n \lambda_n v_n) = c_1^2 \lambda_1 + \cdots + c_n^2 \lambda_n$, then use the fact that $1=\|v\| = c_1^2 + \cdots + c_n^2$.